# Fetching JSON data using JS from a third party

Tags: javascript, json, cors, jsonp

I'm trying to use a certain service to check for proxies. They have a simple API from which they return JSON. I'd like to get this JSON on my server.

No matter what I do, I either get a CORS request problem or a `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` message.

Here's my code:

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<a href="#" onclick="checkProxy()">Test Button</a>


<script>
function checkProxy() {
  console.log("Checking...");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.ip2proxy.com/?ip=105.159.246.30&key=demo',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Clicking my 'button' calls the funtion, which returns the aforementioned syntax error. Changing the datatype to JSON gives me a CORS error.

The strange thing is, when I use a different URL -- example that I found in another StackOverflow thread: `http://www.locationbox.com.tr/locationbox/services?Key=3430000202000191008400080609030X20201090060050260003069&Cmd=IlList` -- it logs the data just fine.

Comment: Then maybe the data isn't meant to be shared publicly. Have you checked the API of the data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to get this JSON on my server.

You'll need to write code that runs **on the server** to do that. The reason your code is failing is that you're running it on a browser, where the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) comes into play: Your page's origin isn't granted access by that API endpoint via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). Unless they allow you access, or they provide a JSONP endpoint you can use instead, you cannot directly query it from a browser.

Comment: So I have to fetch the JSON using PHP?

Comment: @DanielJ: No, but you have to fetch it on a server. You can do that with PHP, Python, JavaScript (in NodeJS, in a JVM), Java, C# or VB .Net, ... :-)

Comment: Ah, right. Sometimes I forget that server side doesn't always mean PHP! It does in my case, though. :) Thank you very much! This has solved my problem. I'm able to get data now.

Comment: @t-j-crowder: So why is it that one example URL I provided gives a syntax error, and the other works? They're both valid JSON.

Comment: @DanielJ: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) != [JSON](http://json.org). Here's an example of a valid JSONP response: `callback({"foo":"bar"})`. Here's an example of a valid JSON response: `{"foo":"bar"}` Your example `ajax` call tells jQuery it's using JSONP. Presumably one of your URLs is, the other isn't.